# Searching IMAP inbox for messages from a specific sender and use of wild cards?

Tags: python, imap

Is it possible to use wildcards in searching for a specific sender on IMAP folder?

```
typ, data = M.SEARCH(None, 'from','"security@website*"')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[IMAP RFC 3501 6.4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4):

> In all search keys that use strings, a message matches the key if
> the string is a substring of the field.  The matching is
> case-insensitive.

So you need to search without * and you should almost similar result.
(you get *security@website* ...)