# PHP IMAP Search With Regex

Tags: php, regex, imap

I am working on a project where I need to search IMAP email with a specific criteria.

I need to check email messages from a pattern email address.

I need to filter email address that contain specific length of number for example 8 or 10, and number must be in sequential order.

By that I mean, if I go for 6 character then:

```
abcd154632xxx@asdf.com
154892@sdfds.com
123456xxx@gmail.com
```

The 3 examples above will work, but `a1b2c3d4e5f6@df.com` will not work because it have 6 numbers but not as a 6 digit number.

So, I tried below:

```
imap_search($conn, 'From "*######*@*"', SE_UID);
```

But it fails.

How can I achieve that? Will regex work for that?

Comment: Nowhere does it say that imap supports wildcards/regexes for searching. you'll probably have to fetch all of the From header lines and search in your code instead.

Comment: @MarcB, thanks for your reply sir, but the problem is i have thousands of emails to proceed that will take decades if process through all :( isn't there nay shorter/faster way?

Comment: No, there isn't.  You either have to use the basic remote search facilities, or grab all the headers and search them yourself.  Also, it does not take decades to download "thousands" of headers, if you don't fetch them one by one.  Thunderbird can sync headers for a mailbox of thousands in a few minutes.

Comment: @Max, thanks for your reply sir, by thousands i mean 30-50+ thousands email. will that can be handle in minutes?

Comment: Depends on your internet connection and how you implement it.

Comment: If you download say, a kb of metadata for each message, 50k is about 50 megs.  That's pretty much nothing these days.

Comment: @Max, thanks again for your reply,  my internet connection is fast enough, but i am not a very expert coder, so, if you can provide sample code for faster implementation that would be great :) ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not here to do your job for you, and I'm not a php programmer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching IMAP inbox for messages from a specefic sender and use of wild cards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719664/searching-imap-inbox-for-messages-from-a-specefic-sender-and-use-of-wild-cards)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the imap_search integration, but the following regex matches what you want :

```
\d{6}.*@
```

It will search for 6 consecutive digits followed by at least an @.